# Error on aapt analyzing: ERROR getting 'android:name' attribute: attribute is not an integer value

Tags: android, aapt

I have a problem when try to load apk to market. My aapt show me these error:

```
package: name='ua.privatbank.gps.android' versionCode='7' versionName='1.1'
sdkVersion:'7'
targetSdkVersion:'16'
uses-permission:'ua.privatbank.gps.android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE'
uses-permission:'com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES'
uses-permission:'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS'
uses-permission:'android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED'
uses-permission:'android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION'
uses-permission:'android.permission.VIBRATE'
uses-gl-es:'0x20000'
application-label:'AutoUchet'
application-label-ka:'сГРсГХсГвсГЭсГРсГжсГасГШсГксГосГХсГР'
application-label-uk:'╨Р╨▓╤В╨╛╨Ю╨▒╨╗i╨║'
application-label-ru:'╨Р╨▓╤В╨╛╨г╤З╨╡╤В'
application-icon-120:'res/drawable-ldpi/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-160:'res/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-240:'res/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-320:'res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png'
application: label='AutoUchet' icon='res/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png'
application-debuggable
launchable-activity: name='ua.privatbank.gps.android.view.MainActivity'  label='
AutoUchet' icon=''
ERROR getting 'android:name' attribute: attribute is not an integer value
```

My Manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="ua.privatbank.gps.android"
android:versionCode="7"
android:versionName="1.1" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<permission
    android:name="ua.privatbank.gps.android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="ua.privatbank.gps.android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="false" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name="@string/app_name"

   android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">

  <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".view.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity  android:name=".view.outlays.OutlaysListActivity"/>
    <activity  android:name=".view.outlays.EditOutlayActivity"/>
    <activity  android:name=".view.cars.CarsListActivity"/>
    <activity  android:name=".view.cars.EditCarActivity"/>
    <activity  android:name=".view.statistic.PageStatisticActivity"/>
    <activity  android:name=".view.preference.SettingsActivity"/>
    <activity  android:name=".view.statistic.CircleDiagramActivity"/>
    <activity  android:name=".view.statistic.ColumnDiagramActivity"/>
    <activity  android:name=".view.tour.TourActivity"/>
    <activity  android:name=".view.map.MapActivity"/>
    <activity  android:name=".view.LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.Dialog"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"
        android:screenOrientation="@string/orientation"/>

    <activity  android:name=".view.NewsActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.Dialog"/>

    <service android:name=".controller.sms.SmsService"/>

 <receiver android:name=".controller.sms.SmsMonitor">
 <intent-filter android:priority="100">
<action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
    <service android:process=":notificationService" 
   android:name=".controller.NotificationService"></service>
    <receiver android:name=".controller.BReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
 </manifest>
```

It's first time, when I faced whith this. Erlier versions loaded without problems. And I think key words is "attribute is not an INTEGER value" (It's a lot of questions and ansvers about STRING value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem hides in this code android:screenOrientation="@string/orientation" becose screenOrientation is int value. I use ="@integer/orientation" instead.